# "git rm" - what is the meaning of "-rf"?

Tags: git

What is the meaning of "-rf" in git?

I used

```
git rm -rf directories
```

but I don't know the actual meaning of -rf

Comment: git and github are two different things. `man git-rm` will tell you what the options of the command are (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html)

Comment: [Here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+rm+-rf+directories) is a nice tool for looking up meanings of shell commands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-r` - Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

`-f` - Override the up-to-date check.

More: `git help rm`